# How to insert rows into a WordPress custom table

Tags: database, wordpress

I know the title makes it look like a question that has been answered already but I checked the similar questions and I'm still not answered.
I have a custom table created with the following code:

```php
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            meta_id int(9) NOT NULL,
            copied tinyint(1) NULL,
            local_url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
            s3_url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

I'm trying to insert rows into it using the following code but nothing is happening:

```php
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 's3images';

$wpdb->insert( 
    $table_name, 
    array( 
        'local_url' => $local_url, 
        's3_url' => $s3_url, 
        'meta_id' => $meta_id, 
        'copied' => 0,
    ) 
);
```

Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query to insert new row in your custom database table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." set local_url='".$local_url."',s3_url='".$s3_url."',meta_id='".$meta_id."',copied='".$copied." ";
$results = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Comment: This looks like a horrible idea. I don't want to know what happens when any of the parameters contain special characters.....